# Hanner inequality: reduction to non-negative functions

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

In Tao's textbook *An Epsilon of Room I*, the exercise 1.4.6 claims that it is possible to reduce to the case when $f,g$ are non-negative in order to prove that
$$\|f+g\|_p^p+\|f-g\|_p^p\ge(\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p)^p+|\|f\|_p-\|g\|_p|^p$$
for all $p\in[1,2]$ and for every $f,g\in L^p(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$ the Lebesgue space of $p$-integrable complex-valued functions on any measure space $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$.

To begin with, I simply can't see why it is possible to reduce to the real case.
From the real case to the non-negative case, I'm ok.

Can you help me with this?

This is self-study of [Hanner inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanner%27s_inequalities), not homework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show
$$
\|f+g\|_p^p+\|f-g\|_p^p=\int|f+g|^p+\int|f-g|^p\ge\int||f|+|g||^p+\int||f|-|g||^p
$$
which can be shown if for $A,B\in \mathbb C$,
$$
|A+B|^p+|A-B|^p\ge||A|+|B||^p+||A|-|B||^p.
$$
Since the both side are invarient under rotation, one may assume $A=a$ is real and $B=be^{\text{i}\theta}$, $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So
$$
|A+B|^p+|A-B|^p=(a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\theta)^{p/2}+(a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta)^{p/2}:=H(\theta).
$$
Some calculation is needed here to show that $H(\theta)$ attain its maximum at $\theta=0$, this gives
$$
|A+B|^p+|A-B|^p\ge H(0)=|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p=||A|+|B||^p+||A|-|B||^p.
$$
Complete.

Comment: I don't see why your first claim (it suffices to show) is correct: it is not that easy to reduce to the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: The right side of the Hanner inequality is invarient under rotation, so you can just replace f,g by |f|,|g|. If the inequality in first claim holds true, you can make the same change in  the left hand side of the inequality you want.